# how can I pass value from iframe src url to parent

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

```
<iframe align="middle" src="http://www.example.com?id=5555555" width="100%" height="300">
</iframe>
```

How can I pass this id value to example.com. Suppose I put this iframe to any webpage and when the iframe loads with the webpage I want to get the value id = 5555555 in example.com.

How to do this, I have tried to google a lot but couldn't get a definite answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, in this case id is a parameter.  That may help your future searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the PHP superglobal $_GET.  in your script, the basic implementation is very simple:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

However, you will want to check the value before you do anything with it, because any user can type into their browser URL bar and change that id value.

If you're going to save it in a database, make sure you escape the value and even better, use a stored procedure.  Scrub it however you can - check the length, the value, anything that can be used to throw off your code.  Failure to do so can result in anything from a silly looking output on a page to a compromised server.

Answer (score 1):

By putting it in the query string, you **have** passed it to `www.example.com`.

Since you've tagged this PHP:

You can retrieve it with `<?php $foo = $_GET['id']; ?>`

Comment: I have tried it ..but somehow its not working... I think this would work if a submit button is clicked on a form but here its only an iframe which is loaded with the webpage

Answer (score 0):

You have to check $_GET array looking for that 'id' key value:

$id = $_GET['id'];

For more info: [PHP: $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)